# Compare selected option value with other variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Does anyone know how to compare a selected value in jQuery?

I have a minimum requirement variable, let's say its `$CD` (Current Degree variable), and then I need to compare it with the selected value on a listbox. The variable A cannot be than the other selected index variable.

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="currentDegree" id="currentDegree">
    <option value="Junior High School">Junior High School</option>
    <option value="Senior High School">Senior High School</option>
    <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
    <option value="Bachelor Degree">Bachelor Degree</option>
    <option value="Master">Master</option>
    <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    var currentDegree = $('#degreeofCollegeoption').val(); // selected option
    var minimumDegree = 3; // i set it for bachelor degree, actuallyit shuld <'<?php echo varX; ?>'> from admin 
    var CD; // dinamic variable ( with selected condition )

    functionCheckDegree(){                                                                      
        // Declare the var cd with value, so it will easilly compared                                           
        if (currentDegree == 'Junior High School') {
            mp = 0;  
        } else if (currentDegree == 'Senior High School') {
            mp = 1; 
        }
        else if (currentDegree == 'Diploma') {
            mp = 2; 
        }
        else if (currentDegree == 'Bachelor Degree') {
            mp = 3; 
        }
        else if (currentDegree == 'Master') {
            mp = 4; 
        }
        else (currentDegree == 'Doctor') {
            mp = 5; 
        } 
    };
    // Compare the currentDegree variable with External variable
    if (mp < minimumDegree) {
        alert(" Current degree is less than Our minimum requirement !");
    }                                                               
</script>
```

I use `onclick="CheckDegree()"` upon submit, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: FYI, there is no benefit in repeating the option's text as the option's `value` attribute.  Just omit the `value` declaration entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** - you are missing a space between `function` and `CheckDegree` - so Javascript won't actually recognise that function.

---

If you want to call that function on submit, you'll need to put an action inside it. Currently your function is just assigning a variable, and the actual comparison and `alert` section is outside the function:

```
function CheckDegree(){                                                                      
    // Declare the var cd with value, so it will easilly compared                                           
    if (currentDegree == 'Junior High School') {
        mp = 0;  
    } else if (currentDegree == 'Senior High School') {
        mp = 1; 
    } else if (currentDegree == 'Diploma') {
        mp = 2; 
    } else if (currentDegree == 'Bachelor Degree') {
        mp = 3; 
    } else if (currentDegree == 'Master') {
        mp = 4; 
    } else (currentDegree == 'Doctor') {
        mp = 5; 
    } 
    // Compare the currentDegree variable with External variable
    if (mp < minimumDegree) {
        alert(" Current degree is less than Our minimum requirement !");
        return false; // you'll probably want to do this if it's stopping your form action
    } 
};
```

On another note here, wouldn't it be easier to put the `mp` values as the values of the `option` elements - that's what `value` is for. E.g.:

```
<option value="0">Junior High School</option>
<option value="1">Senior High School</option>
```

Then you can simplify your function to this:

```
function CheckDegree(){                                                                      
    var currentDegree = $('#currentDegree').val(); // selected option
    var minimumDegree = 3;

    if (parseInt(currentDegree) < minimumDegree) {
        alert(" Current degree is less than Our minimum requirement !");
        return false; // you'll probably want to do this if it's stopping your form action
    }
};
```